# Strange Gradient

Tags: modeling, rendering, mesh

This is my first modeling try at a person, and I am still quite new to blender, but I was wondering if anyone knew why I get this gradient in my object? It seems to be along some of the edges. Even worse, they appear to show up on cycles render, not entirely sure what is going on, please help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also check for disconnected or  dupliacted vertices

Comment: Read also:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70209/strange-shading

Comment: maybe you have inside faces? please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/