# Newbie Shading problems!

Tags: modeling

i run into some problems with the shading in the tail of the airplane. but i did not know what cause the problem. can any help?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70209/strange-shading

Comment: Thanks for helping this...